# Installation error mysql 5.7 on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-5.7

When I try to execute the following command to install mysql 5.7 in ubuntu 20.04 machine the following error appears. I am following the documentation in here https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-focal/ when installing the mysql.

```
sudo apt install -f mysql-client=5.7* mysql-community-server=5.7* mysql-server=5.7*
```

```
Setting up mysql-common (5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Setting up libtinfo5:amd64 (6.2-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up mysql-community-client (5.7.35-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Setting up mysql-client (5.7.35-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Setting up mysql-community-server (5.7.35-1ubuntu18.04) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /etc/my.cnf at line 1!
my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /etc/my.cnf at line 1!
my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /etc/my.cnf at line 1!
my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /etc/my.cnf at line 1!
my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mysql.service → /lib/systemd/system/mysql.service.
Setting up mysql-server (5.7.35-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.11) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
```

And the **/etc/mysql/my.cnf** file has only the following lines, others are commented and it is the default file.

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

When I check the **/etc/mysql/conf.d/** directory, following files were there.

**mysql.cnf**

```
[mysql]
```

**mysqldump.cnf**

```
[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
```

When I check the **/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/** directory, following file were there.

**mysqld.cnf**

```
[mysqld]
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
log-error   = /var/log/mysql/error.log
# By default we only accept connections from localhost
bind-address    = 127.0.0.1
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
```

And the **/etc/my.cnf** file looks like below.

```
basedir=/var/lib/mariadb/mysql
datadir=/var/lib/mariadb
user=mysql
```

Comment: your conf file has an error post it but a group  is signified in [mysqld] and all options have to be under the right one

Comment: these lines should run witholuit [mysq] you have to check the directpories and see if there are also my.com files

Comment: @nbk can you check the files I have added here?

Comment: they are also ok see if you have /etc/my.cnf

Comment: In /etc/my.cnf there are 2 directories listed (I added them in the description), but they are not existing. What needs to do?

Comment: add [mysql] at the beginning like i said every option has to have a group

Comment: Now when I try to login it gives the error --> mysql: [ERROR] unknown variable 'basedir=/var/lib/mariadb/mysql'

Comment: I created those 2 directories manually

Comment: this belongs to [mysqld]

Comment: Commented out the following 2 lines and now it works. ```basedir=/var/lib/mariadb/mysql
datadir=/var/lib/mariadb```

Comment: Hope commenting out these will not lead to other issues!

Comment: add the lines to mysqld.cnf or add at the beginning [mysqld]

Comment: /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf file already has a different datadir.

Comment: then remove the one that is wrong. afaik you can only have one of them

Answer (score -1):

sudo su
apt install mysql-server mysql-client

it will work

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. `sudo su` looks pretty strange to me, and that won't resolve any errors in the configuration file either